# a template function for obtaining the maximum value as well as its corresponding index in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

It is not difficult to write a function that can give you the maximum value as well as its corresponding index in a vector array as the following codes show:

```
using namespace std;



std::vector<double> line_weighting;
line_weighting.push_back(22);
line_weighting.push_back(8);
line_weighting.push_back(55);
line_weighting.push_back(19);



std::vector<double>::iterator   it =  std::max_element(line_weighting.begin(),line_weighting.end());
int index = distance(line_weighting.begin(),it);
value = *it;
```

I am more interested in a more general function using template that can perform the same kind of functionality:

```
template<typename T>
     int max_with_index(const std::vector<T> &weighting, T &max_value)
     {
         std::vector<T>::iterator  it = max_element(weighting.begin(),weighting.end());
         max_value =   *it;
         return (std::distance(weighting.begin(),it));
     }
```

However, this function cannot compile as it has the following error in VC2010:

```
Error   2   error C2782: 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type std::distance(_InIt,_InIt)' : template parameter '_InIt' is ambiguous 
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'
```

I know that if I write this function this way, it can work.

```
  template<typename T>
     int max_with_index(const std::vector<T> &weighting, T &max_value)
     {
        // std::vector<T>::iterator  it = max_element(weighting.begin(),weighting.end());
         auto  it= max_element(weighting.begin(),weighting.end());
         max_value =   *it;
         return (std::distance(weighting.begin(),it));
     }
```

But I cannot understand why my original implementation has compilation error, and can I do something to correct it?

Comment: Why would you not make this generic over a range (pair of iterators) rather than a more limited vector?

Comment: @ David Rodríguez - dribeas I don't understand what you refer to, and could you give me an example?

Comment: You are trying to write a helper to avoid writing what, 3 lines of code? But instead of providing a general solution you provide one for only `std::vector`... An alternative `template <typename Iterator> typename Iterator::difference_type max_with_index(Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator::value_type& max)` would be usable with different containers (`std::deque`, `std::array`, raw arrays). I don't see value in limiting the usage to only `std::vector` using the default allocator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare different types of iterators, you need to use `const_iterator` as `weighting` is **const**

```
std::vector<T>::const_iterator  it = max_element(weighting.begin(),weighting.end());
```

That's why `auto` is so good in C++11.

Comment: Thanks, and it works. I am often confused with const_iterator and const iterator.

Comment: Jut use the `auto` keyword, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Vector has two types of iterators, `const_iterator` and regular `iterator`, these are different types and therefore can't be converted from one to the other.

You should change

```
  std::vector<T>::iterator  it = ...
```

To

```
  std::vector<T>::const_iterator  it = ...
```

Or better yet let the compiler do the work for you:

```
  auto  it = ...
```